Как дополнять переменную данными с словаря очищенными от квадратных скобок?
есть вот такой словарь
a = {1: ['Антон', 'Артем'], 2: ['Сергей']}

нужно дополнять переменную записывая с словаря данные
с = "\n".join([f'{name} на {place}' for place, name in a.items()])

но выводит с скобками
['Антон', 'Артем'] на 1
['Сергей'] на 2

а нужно так
Антон, Артем на 1
Сергей на 2

Способ с распаковкой в print отпадает также как и через [0]!

Просто объединяйте элементы последовательности тем же ', '.join(name):
a = {1: ['Антон', 'Артем'], 2: ['Сергей']}

c = "\n".join([f'{', '.join(name)} на {place}' for place, name in a.items()])

print(c)

output:
(.venv) PS C:\KWORK> & c:/KWORK/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/KWORK/MyUserBot/ruSo.py
Антон, Артем на 1
Сергей на 2


спасибо! Можно еще один вопрос задать потому что вижу что вы также работаете с aiogram-ом.
(КД на вопросы)
Есть такой код
a = "Apple<.3"
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
f'Переменная a = {a}')
Но telegram api вызывает ошибку потому что не может отформатировать <.3

@Алексей Один вопрос — один ответ. Вас никто не ограничивает, если есть вопрос — задавайте! Но не в комментариях, а отдельным вопросом (на ruSO Вам обязательно ответят).

Воздержитесь от рекламы своих фрилансовых услуг, пожалуйста.

@SVBazuev Воздержитесь от рекламы своих фрилансовых услуг, пожалуйста. –  strawdog @strawdog
